# derivative of Riemann zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory

One can of course give a power series for the derivative of RiemannZeta.  But is there a "closed form",  e.g. expressible in the field of functions generated by Zeta and Gamma and some constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this has what you're looking for?

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2007806

Comment: Could you provide a brief summary of the result you have in mind?  A bare link is rather uninviting.